# How to display the xml parsing data in the UItextfield in iphone

Tags: iphone, xml-parsing, uitextfield, uilabel

I am able to parse the xml data and able to display it in the console, but not able to display that data in the `UITextField` or in `UILabel`.

I tried to assign to textfield in the `viewDidLoad` method also.

The following is my code,

```
NSMutableString *currentNodeContent;
NSXMLParser *parser;
ViewController *currentProfile;
bool isStatus;

ViewController *xmlParser;

-(id)loadXMLByURL:(NSString *)urlString
{
    _profile = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    parser.delegate = self;
    [parser parse];
    return self;
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"profileinfo"])
    {
        currentProfile = [ViewController alloc];
        isStatus = YES;
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"first_name"])
    {
        currentProfile = [ViewController alloc];
        isStatus = YES;
    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"first_name"])
    {
        currentProfile.firstName = currentNodeContent;
        NSLog(@"%@",currentProfile.firstName);
        first_Name.text = currentNodeContent;//UITextField
        first_name.text = currentNodeContent;//Label

    }
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"last_name"])
    {
        currentProfile.lastName = currentNodeContent;
         NSLog(@"%@",currentProfile.lastName);
        last_Name.text = currentProfile.lastName;
    }
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"profileinfo"])
    {
        [self.profile addObject:currentProfile];
        currentProfile = nil;
        currentNodeContent = nil;
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    xmlParser = [[ViewController alloc] loadXMLByURL:@"http://www.mxxxxx.net/xxx/xxxxx.aspx?type=proifileinfo&loginid=xxx@gmail.com"];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of assigning the values directly to the 'UITextField' or 'UILabel', have the values stored in a string. And when the parsing action completed, assign the string value to the 'UITextField' or 'UILabel'; Probably you should do that in '-viewWillAppear' method :-)

Comment: I stored the values to the string and then assigned to the textfield, even then it is not displaying anything in the textfield.

Comment: You are having the textField in XIB or code? If code, have you properly initialized it?

Comment: I have the textfield in XIB and given all the connections properly

Comment: Ok.. Tried printing the value in console? You able to get it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a IBOutlet UILabel *label; in the interface, connect it in Interface Builder, and then you can set the text of it by label.text = @"Anything";

Comment: ,I have created a IBOutlet UILabel and connected in the interface builder, even then its not showing anything in the label.

Answer (score 0):

I have also the same problem while parsing XML parser.

```
currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}
```

You are using the above line to trim spaces and tabs. But sometimes It does not work.

So, I implement the following code. The code may be useful to you.

```
NSString *sname = [currentNodeContent stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];

NSString *actualString = [sname stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\t" withString:@""];
```

Then pass the `actualString` to whatever you required.